# menu com a opção selecionada de outra cor em angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

minha primeira pergunta e meu primeiro projeto "de verdade" também. Estou usando bootstrap, html/css e angular e tenho um menu horizontal em lista não ordenada. O que eu preciso fazer é com que esse menu tenha outra cor na opção que eu clicar, mas não deu certo usando o ng-class. Ele precisa ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

onde "Inicio", "Perfil" e "Usuários" são as opções e eu estou na tela de início nesse caso.

Meu código está assim (ainda incompleto): e eu não sei o que usar do angular pra fazer isso.

(Eu fiz um `<ul ng-model="classe">`+ `<a ng-class="classe"></a>` mas não funcionou)

```
<div class="menu-superior">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#inicio">Início</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Perfil</a></li>
        <li><a href="#buscar_usuario">Usuários</a></li>            
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Consegui resolver usando

```
$scope.getClass = function (path) {
        if ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) === path) {
            return 'active';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    };
```

no controller e no menu

```
<li><a ng-class="getClass('/buscar_usuario')" href="#buscar_usuario">...</a></li>
```

Comment: atualizei minha resposta da uma olhada.

Answer (score 2):

Como você pretende fazer isso no menu, existem modos mais 'práticos' de se obter esse resultado. Se você está utilizando o ui-router, [pode ler mais sobre ele aqui](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), basta você inserir uma linha com a seguinte expressão `ui-sref-active="nomedaclasse"`. No seu caso, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
<li><a ui-sref="inicio" ui-sref-active="active">Início</a></li>
```

Deste modo, a classe será aplicada automaticamente naquele menu, quando ele estiver na página 'Início'.

Para usar o ng-class de modo isolado, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': menu == inicio}">Link</li> //Aplica a classe se o menu for igual a 'inicio'

<li ng-class="{'active': meuValor}">Link</li> //Aplica a classe se 'meuValor' for true

<li ng-class="{'active': !meuValor}">Link</li> //Aplica a classe se 'meuValor' for false

<li ng-class="{'active': meuValor && !outroValor}">Link</li> //Aplica a classe se 'meuValor' for true e 'outroValor' for false

<li ng-class="{'active': meuValor, 'disable':!outroValor}">Link</li> //Aplica a classe 'active' se 'meuValor' for true; aplica classe "disable" se 'outroValor' for false
```

Como você está iniciando, recomendo que dê uma olhada também no ui-router, pois notei que você está usando a navegação com #.

Qualquer dúvida, só questionar.

Answer (score 0):

O `ng-class` deve ser utilizado com o nome de uma classe e uma expressão:

```
<ANY class="ng-class: expressao;"> ... </ANY>
```

Um exemplo de código meu:

```
<li ng-class="{active : geral.navID == 'home'}"><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
```

Nesse meu código o `li` fica com a classe `active` apenas quando a variável `geral.navID` for igual a `home`.

Você também vai precisar de uma variável de controle exatamente para manter o estado de `ativo` do menu. Ai em cada troca de página você atualiza o valor dela para a página atual.

Comment: essa variável de controle seria algo como para identificar qual elemento foi clicado? (desculpa, mas a parte de js (ou a programação propriamente dita) é mais complexo pra mim).

Comment: Essa variável seria para identificar qual a página ativa, e refletir isso no menu com um efeito. @trofonia